# Java Beginner, Class Constructor error, no arguments found

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

I am trying to practice just writing a simple application with basic java concepts to reinforce these in my mind and I am getting an error that I can't seem to figure out. I'm sure this is some stupid oversight on my part, or perhaps something I don't know yet as I am learning. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

This is the message I get when trying to compile this code below:

```
error: constructor Dice in class Dice cannot be applied to given types;
        Dice di = new Dice();
                  ^
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
3 errors



//import statements
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;



class Dice 
{//Begin Dice Class

    //initiate constructor for "Random" class
    Random r = new Random();

    //declare Dice class variables
    int p1d6 = r.nextInt(6-0) + 1;
    int p2d6 = r.nextInt(6-0) + 1;


    //initiate class constructors
    public Dice (int p1d6, int p2d6)
    {
        this.p1d6 = p1d6;
        this.p2d6 = p2d6;
    }


    //create set and get methods for class variables
    public void setP1d6(int p1d6)
    {
        this.p1d6 = p1d6;
    }
    public int getP1d6()
    {
        return p1d6;
    }


    public void setP2d6(int p2d6)
    {
        this.p2d6 = p2d6;
    }
    public int getP2d6()
    {
        return p2d6;
    }


    //toString method that outputs the class variables
    //public String toString ()
    //{
    //  return "P1D6: " + p1d6 + "\n" + "P2D6: " + p2d6 + "\n";
    //}

}// End Dice Class

public class DiceGame2
{
    public static void main( String ars[] )
    {

        //initiate constructor for Dice class
        Dice di = new Dice();

        System.out.println( "--- Welcome to the Dice Game v2! ---" ); // welcomes player
        System.out.println("P1D6: " + di.getP1d6() + "\n");
        System.out.println("P2D6: " + di.getP2d6() + "\n");
        System.out.println("P1D6: " + di.getP1d6() + "\n");
        System.out.println("P2D6: " + di.getP2d6() + "\n");
        System.out.println("P1D6: " + di.getP1d6() + "\n");
        System.out.println("P2D6: " + di.getP2d6() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only constructor you created takes 2 arguments

```
public Dice (int p1d6, int p2d6)
{
    this.p1d6 = p1d6;
    this.p2d6 = p2d6;
}
```

You are trying to create a Dice object with 0 arguments

```
Dice di = new Dice();
```

There are 2 was solutions, first, you could change you the way you are calling the constructor.

```
Dice di = new Dice(1, 2);
```

Second, you could create a Constuctor in your Dice class that takes 0 arguments.

```
public Dice()
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your Dice constructor takes 2 ints as arguments. You're trying to call the constructor without supplying those arguments. Either supply those arguments, or create a constructor that doesn't take arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a no-args constructor

```
    //initiate constructor for Dice class
    Dice di = new Dice();
```

is  problem when you declared that the only constructor required arguments:

```
    public Dice (int p1d6, int p2d6)
```